# why if-statement not shown in opcode?

Tags: python, bytecode

Here is a simple sample:

```py
>>> def foo():
...     if True:
...             return 'yes'
... 
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  3           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('yes')
              2 RETURN_VALUE
```

Why does here not have bytecode about if-statement? It just directly return value.

- CPython3.6

Comment: The optimiser was able to prove that the `if` statement will always be `True`, so it omitted the check and the other branch

Comment: This is one of the very few things that Python can statically optimize.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python 3, `True` cannot be overridden, so Python is allowed to "optimize" this and assume `True` will always be true.

For historic reasons, Python 2 didn't have `True` as a constant/keyword, so the language isn't allowed to optimize this:

```
Python 2.7.16 (default, May  8 2021, 11:48:02) 
[GCC Apple LLVM 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.19.59.6) [+internal-os, ptrauth-isa=deploy on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def foo():
...     if True:
...         return 'yes'
... 
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (True)
              3 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       10

  3           6 LOAD_CONST               1 ('yes')
              9 RETURN_VALUE        
        >>   10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE
```

So historically, in Python 2 you could (even though you never should) set `True = 213` or even `True = 0` (or `True = False`) and mess up your program logic:

```
>>> True = 0
>>> print(foo())
None
>>> True = 1
>>> print(foo())
yes
```

In Python 3, this is not possible:

```
Python 3.9.5 (default, May  4 2021, 03:36:27) 
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> True = 213
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    True = 213
    ^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to True
```

Do note that `if True` is a special case, as Python 3 cannot optimize other tautologies (yet):

```
>>> def foo():
...     if 3 == 3:
...         return 'yes'
... 
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (3)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (3)
              4 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
              6 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       12

  3           8 LOAD_CONST               2 ('yes')
             10 RETURN_VALUE
        >>   12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             14 RETURN_VALUE
```

Note that this is implementation-specific (CPython), in PyPy 3 it's slightly different again; it can figure out that `if True` is always `True`, but then also generates byte code for the implicit `return None` at the end of the function (that never gets executed):

```
Python 3.7.10 (51efa818fd9b24f625078c65e8e2f6a5ac24d572, Apr 08 2021, 17:43:00)
[PyPy 7.3.4 with GCC Apple LLVM 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>> def foo():
....     if True:
....         return 'yes'
....         
>>>> import dis
>>>> dis.dis(foo)
  3           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('yes')
              2 RETURN_VALUE
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

And again for completeness' sake, PyPy with Python 2.7 semantics isn't allowed to optimize away the `True`, as it could be set to something else (here the code for the implicit `return None` is correct, as it may get executed depending on what you set `True` to):

```
Python 2.7.18 (63df5ef41012b07fa6f9eaba93f05de0eb540f88, Apr 08 2021, 15:53:40)
[PyPy 7.3.4 with GCC Apple LLVM 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>> def foo():
....     if True:
....         return 'yes'
....         
>>>> import dis
>>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (True)
              3 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       10

  3           6 LOAD_CONST               1 ('yes')
              9 RETURN_VALUE        
        >>   10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE
```

**How it is implemented in CPython**

The optimization is implemented in CPython 3 in `optimize_basic_block()` in `Python/compile.c`, as of this writing [this line](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ec8759b060eff83ff466f42c5a96d83a685016ce/Python/compile.c#L8029) ("Remove LOAD_CONST const; conditional jump") does the optimization. In other words, the compiler generates opcode like this:

```
  LOAD_CONST ... (True)
  POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE x
  LOAD_CONST ... ('yes')
  RETURN_VALUE
x LOAD_CONST ... (None)
  RETURN_VALUE
```

So if it sees a `LOAD_CONST` followed by a `POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE`, and it can prove that the constant is `True` at compile time, it will remove the `LOAD_CONST` and will turn the `POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE` into a `JUMP_ABSOLUTE` or into a `NOP`, depending on the boolean value calculated (here it will turn it into a `NOP`):

```
  NOP
  NOP
  LOAD_CONST ... ('yes')
  RETURN_VALUE
x LOAD_CONST ... (None)
  RETURN_VALUE
```

Further steps (`clean_basic_block()`) would then remove the NOPs (no operation) and probably additional steps would figure out that code after `RETURN_VALUE` is dead and remove that.